# Haskell Bytestring change ASCII?

Tags: haskell, ascii, bytestring

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

stuff <- BS.readFile "stuff.txt"
```

How do take a specific character from a bytestring then change its ASCII and then put it back?
Do I use readInt or something?

Ex: "aaaaa" ,"a" is 97 so minus 1 and you have "aa`aa"

Comment: You should look at `Data.Text` for unicode support. I would replace any instance of `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` with `Data.Text.Lazy` and use `Text` support. `Data.ByteString` should be used for binary.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of changing your question into a completely different one. I've reverted the edit as it made the existing answers here irrelevant and confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have addressed the problem of doing the byte operations, so I will focus on the other half of your question: selecting and updating a particular byte within a `ByteString`. Let's start with implementing the operation for plain lists, using a more familiar interface:

```
onNth :: Int -> (a -> a) -> ([a] -> [a])
onNth n f xs = case splitAt n xs of
    (beginning, x:ending) -> beginning ++ f x : ending
    _ -> xs -- happens when n is out-of-bounds
```

You might equivalently implement this using `take` and `drop` instead of `splitAt`. Now, how can we translate this to work on `ByteString`s? Well, the `ByteString` interface offers `take`, `drop`, `splitAt`, `append`, and `cons`; the only thing we haven't quite got available is the pattern matching that we did in the `x:ending` part above. Luckily, `ByteString` does offer something similar:

```
uncons :: ByteString -> Maybe (Word8, ByteString)
```

So, using that, we can write a new `onNth` function that works for `ByteString`s:

```
second :: (b -> c) -> (a, b) -> (a, c)
second f (a, b) = (a, f b)

onNth :: Int -> (Word8 -> Word8) -> (ByteString -> ByteString)
onNth n f bs = case second uncons (splitAt n bs) of
    (beginning, Just (x, ending)) -> append beginning (cons (f x) ending)
    _ -> bs -- again, for out-of-bounds cases
```

Finally, we can discuss what function we should use as the `f :: Word8 -> Word8` argument above. Although you talk about text above, I will point out that you shouldn't be using `ByteString` for text anyway (`ByteString`s are sequences of bytes, not sequences of `Char`s). Therefore, if you have chosen to use `ByteString`, you must be talking about bytes, not text. ;-)

Therefore, you really meant to ask about a function which decreases a *byte* by one, presumably wrapping around on a boundary. `subtract 1` is a function that does exactly that, so to convert `pack [97, 97, 97, 97, 97]` to `pack [97, 97, 96, 97, 97]`, you might write `onNth 2 (subtract 1)`. Reads almost like English!

Answer (score 2):

How about `BS.map pred`? You can also use `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to make convert to / from `Int`s.

Comment: In which library can I find prev?

Comment: <interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `prev'

Comment: @Haskeller Sorry, I spelled it wrong. It is `pred` in reality. Please notice, that `pred` does not wraps.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've converted the bytes to `Char`s with `BS.unpack`, you can use `fromEnum :: Char -> Int` (or, equivalently, `ord` from `Data.Char`) to convert a `Char` to its ASCII value, which you can then manipulate like a normal integer.  To convert an ASCII value from an `Int` back to a `Char`, use `toEnum` or `Data.Char.chr`, and the `Char`s can then be converted back to a `ByteString` with `BS.pack` or similar.